# Knockout how to print a value from another lookup table

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an object that I like to read it's value from another observableArray as a lookup. here is a link to it http://jsfiddle.net/928FQ/.

I have a select list that is populated correctly and it's showing the correct selection based on the row values, but how can I change the "surcharge" column from "0" to "cheap". it looks like `options` tag is only available for `select`. Any help would be great.

**HTML:**

```
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: meal().mealName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
        <td><select data-bind="options: $parent.priceLookup, optionsText: 'defenition', optionsValue: 'price', value: meal().price"></select>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ]; 
    self.priceLookup = ko.observableArray([
        { price:0, defenition: 'cheap'},
        { price:34.95, defenition: 'average'}
   ]); 

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

Comment: I've added the code from the fiddle to the post. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149890/153691) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ko.computed` is a good choice for this type of behavior.  The harder decision is where and how to wire it into the existing data set.

Here's an example of one way to do it.  You may want to structure it differently, but it should get you started.  Demonstration:  http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/928FQ/1/

Here's the relevant code: I added a utility function, `getMealForBinding`, that applies a `ko.computed` to the meal object.  In this example, I'm overwriting the computed each time, but you may want to implement some smarter logic.

```
// Editable data
self.seats = ko.observableArray([
    new SeatReservation("Steve", getMealForBinding(self.availableMeals[0])),
    new SeatReservation("Bert", getMealForBinding(self.availableMeals[1]))
]);

//add functionality to basic meal object
function getMealForBinding(meal){
    meal.friendlyPrice = ko.computed(function(){
        var price = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.priceLookup(), function(p){
            return p.price === meal.price;
        });
        if( price!=null){
           return price.defenition;
        };
        return "unknown";
    });

    return meal;
}
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. I had the computed function but I was passing the `meal.price' and just returning the value, and it wasn't working properly, but now that I pass the observable and creating a new property, it works just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). Then you can have that field calculated based on what you want. It could be checking another value, looking something up in an arrey, etc.

Try this:

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
    self.priceLookup = ko.computed(function(){
        if (self.meal().price < 34.95)
            return 'cheap';
        else if (self.meal().price < 100)
            return 'average';
    }, self); 
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ]; 

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[1])
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```